# How to sort an array of mongoid documents (array contains different mongoid document types)?

Tags: ruby, arrays, mongodb, sorting, mongoid

I have two arrays of Mongoid documents, `FirstType` documents and `SecondType` documents. Both are embedded in `User`.

```
user.first_types  =  [#<FirstType _id: 51a10b4883c336ebef0002a8, created_at: 2013-05-25 19:04:40 UTC, updated_at: 2013-05-25 19:04:40 UTC, datetime: 2013-03-28 15:03:22 UTC, text: "Hello 1">]
user.second_types = [#<SecondType _id: 51a6058783c3368a62000003, created_at: 2013-05-29 13:41:27 UTC, updated_at: 2013-05-29 13:41:27 UTC, datetime: 2013-05-29 08:23:27 UTC, text: "Hello 2">]
```

Then I merge them with this line of code:

```
all_types = user.first_types+user.second_types
```

I now wish to sort the all_types array by the attribute `datetime` (newest `datetime` first, so the `SecondType` object should be the first one).

I have tried the conventional Mongoid and Ruby array methods, but they don't seem to work when  I mix up Mongoid documents. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) and negate the numeric value of the "datetime" attribute for descending order:

```
all_types.sort_by { |x| -x.datetime.to_f }
```

Comment: why `-x.datetime.to_f` not only `x.datetime`? ?

Comment: @RubyLovely: for descending order "newest datetime first".

Comment: why not `all_types.sort_by { |x| x.datetime }.reverse` ?

Comment: @RubyLovely: because it's faster to just sort in the desired direction.

Comment: @RubyLovely: sure, anybody can.  You could, for example! =)